# Favorites or Recents? Which should be more prior?

Tags: interaction-design, mobile-application, hierarchy, travel

In an airlines app, when you're choosing Departure(From) and Arrival(To) destinations, ports are shown under different categories such as:

1. Nearby (Only when choosing Departure[From])
2. Favorites
3. Recently Searched
4. All Airports

I couldn't decide if Favorites or Recently Searched should be on top, what are your ideas about this case? Especially in small screens, as keyboard covers the bottom part of the page, users will probably only see one of them without scrolling so I thought this was an important decision to make.

[image: screens]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think recently searched should be on top.It depends on the use case still recent works better as if the user has travelled recently  to one of the favourites it is automatically listed there.

Alternatively, you can also show favourites before user enter "From and To" so that user can choose favourites (Routes or destination).